# NUM Lock turns off and on

Tags: windows-xp

Can anyone help me out. I changed the keyboard, OS (Win XP) seems to be ok, but the NUM Lock turns off and on spontaneously. (this happens at work on several computers and it's pretty annoying)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could it be there is a software installed by the manufacturer of the computers that interferes with the new keyboard?

Something like an On-Screen-Display software that displays on the screen the status change of the CAPS Lock, NumLock, ... , the volume, ...

[image]

Or a tool that uses NumLock to display alerts by blinking the LED, or using the NumLock LED as a network indicator, or a disk activity indicator? [**Network Light**](http://www.itsamples.com/network-lights.html)s for instance.

Comment: no, there is nothing like this

Comment: Not even a Dell QuickSet tool or equivalent for other manufacturers?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a software issue (unless several computers exhibit the same hardware issue - which is possible, e.g. a KVM switch used by all of them - but unlikely) , and unless you are running some stange software on all of them - my bet is on some kind of malware.